# Google+ like ViewPager page indicator

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, indicator

im trying to customize [this](http://www.zylinc.com/blog-reader/items/viewpager-page-indicator.html) page indicator with half succes, but after many hours im stuck and i dont know whats the problem.
So i want to change the titles for fix day names, from monday to friday, without weekends, and the start position is the current day.
Currently  the names are okay,but when i start the app, the current position is friday and the next is saturday, when i swipe, the titles change back to normal, mon to fry.
So the problem is the start position.

Here is the code for the titles.

```
public String getTitle(int pos){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 2);
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, pos);
        return readableDateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
    }
```

And for the position i used this.

`static int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
if(day==0 || day==7) 
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
else mViewPager.setCurrentItem(day);`

Before i changed the titles the positioning worked well.
So if anyone know what i did wrong please help.

Comment: nevermind, i just found the problem, it was my fault, i thought monday 's number is 1.
the solution is: 


`if(day==7 || day==8){
   mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
  }
  else {
   mViewPager.setCurrentItem(day-2);
  }`

Comment: Nice work executioner. As a friendly reminder, can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just found the problem, it was my fault, i thought monday 's number is 1. the solution is:

`if(day==7 || day==8){ mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0); } else { mViewPager.setCurrentItem(day-2); }`